# How to change \thepage when using alphalph?

Tags: page-numbering, counters

The following MWE, in which I'm trying to change `\thepage` in order to show both the chapter number and the page, does not compile if the `alphalph` package is loaded. How should it be done?

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\begin{document}
\appendix
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\AlphAlph{chapter}-\arabic{page}}
\chapter{First}
\end{document}
```

> ! Missing number, treated as zero.
>   to be read again
>   c
>   l.15 \end{document}
>   A number should have been here; I inserted 0.
>   (If you can't figure out why I needed to see a number,
>   look up `weird error' in the index to The TeXbook.)
>   ! Missing = inserted for \ifnum.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `alphalph` commands needs `\value{countername}` instead of the counter name only, just like `\number`, e.g.

`\number\value{countername}`

always will print the counter as a number, not as defined `\thecountername`, which could have been defined somewhere else to be totally different what is expected.

The correct usage of `\AlphAlph` is

```
\AlphAlph{\value{countername}}
```

then.

If the counter value is in the interval from `1` to `26`, then `\Alph{countername}` is perhaps a simpler(?), quicker(?) alternative.

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{alphalph}
\begin{document}
\appendix
\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\AlphAlph{\value{chapter}}-\arabic{page}}
\chapter{First}
\end{document}
```

*I omitted a screen shot, since everybody can imagine a page number 'A-1' ;-)*

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Actually it's enough with `\Alph`, but I'm writing a template and I want to add the option to switch easily to `\AlphAlph`. I though I could just do `\let\origAlph\Alph` and `\let\Alph\AlphAlph`. But, as you pointed out, it's not so easy...

Comment: I use a `\ProvideValue` command with one argument, which handles either the direct value if the argument is no counter and otherwise it will use `\value{countername}` automatically.

Comment: Yo mean writing something like `\newcommand\ProvideValue[1]{ if#1counter #1 \else \value{#1} \fi }`?

Comment: Yes, something like that, best in a wrapper. (`\ifltxcounter` command from `etoolbox` works very good for this!)

Comment: I don't really get it :S. If I define `\newcommand\ProvideValue[1]{ \ifltxcounter{#1}{#1}{\value{#1}} }`, then doing `\Alph(\ProvideValue{chapter})` or `\AlphAlph(\ProvideValue{chapter})` will both have the same `#1`, won't they?